# How to handle new domain names?

Tags: seo, website-design

I have a  new product which I'll call a pen ink reloader. I have a website using my products name, for example, www.inkywink.com which I want to have accessed by searches for keywords such as  "pen ink", "pen out of ink" "ink for pens" etc. , since nobody knows that a pen ink reloader exists.

I see that its quite difficult to get on front page for these keywords since they have lots of competition. However I notice that the exact phrases I want to rank highly for are available as domains. I purchase "www.penink.com" and "penoutofink.com"
which for arguments sake are highly searched and the perfect keywords to get eyes on my money site www.inkywink.com .

1. What is my best option to leverage those names so that they appear near top of searches so that  I can get traffic to my money site? Do I just have them redirect 301 to inkywink.com or should I create small original content on each with links to my main site?
2. If I just have them redirected to inkywink.com, am I able to use keywords in metatag and headers for each site separately or do they all automatically obtain the same headers and tags as the site to which they're redirected ?

Thanks to anyone who can help as I'm a real newbie to all this.

Answer (score 3):

I think now is a bad time to start new Exact match domain (EMD) websites. Google has began to crack down on low quality EMD websites: http://searchengineland.com/the-emd-update-like-panda-penguin-expect-further-refreshes-to-come-135446. So creating low quality mini-sites will not be an effective use of time.

Instead spend time building up your brand for your main website. At least that way all links and PR you build will all benefit your one website.

Your home page should target your main keyword, and have your subpages target your secondary keywords.